# how access to odoo from outside the local network?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I installed Odoo-8 on Windows 7 and I would like to know if it is possible to access remotely (outside the local network)
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: your question has 2 parts in it. First how to setup Odoo for production. Tips for that: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/setup/deploy.html
Second is how to expose your server to outside the local network. Its same as for every server. But if you want more exact help then you need to describe your local network.

Comment: the second question that interests me I have an ADSL with a D-link modem.